# How to pass 40 parameters efficiently in Mysql auroraDb

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure in mysql which will insert data in 4 tables under one atomic transaction. I have a total of 40 fields to be inserted which would mean passing 40 input parameters to the stored proc.

Is there a way to do this in a different way by not having a stored procedure which accepts 40 input parameters ?

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure anyways? You just need to use the insert command

Comment: because I have multiple inserts and I need to put them all in a transaction and rollback the whole transaction if anything goes wrong.

Comment: What/who will call this procedure? Is it a programming language or will you run it inside a mysql client? because if it is a programming language the transaction can be controlled in the application level, and therefore just the inserts will do... if you are calling this inside the database itself then the simple answer is *no* (for the simple way)... a more complex way would be to insert those data in a temporary table and fetch then into the procedure code which is the same level of ugliness.